# Find files with comments in Finder search?

Tags: macos, finder, spotlight, search, extended-attributes

How can I find all the files on my system that have a Finder comment (the one you can see in "Comments" when using "Get Info")?

Answer (score 3):

For everyone that has been trying to find files with "Get Info" comments, here is the definitive answer on how to Search comments **and** have a **REUSABLE** search tool on hand.

Open a Finder window, then use the keyboard command to perform Find (⌘+F). This will open a new tab in the Finder window.

Click on "This Mac" (green) so that the search will look through all of your directories (including those in iCloud), then click on the filter options (yellow): **(fig. 01)**

[image: Image_01]

If the filter option "Spotlight Comment" is not visible, choose "Other...": **(fig. 02)**

[image: Image_02]

Find the search attribute "Spotlight Comment" and check the "In Menu" box so that it will stay as a filter option, then click "OK": **(fig. 03)**

[image: Image_03]

Click on the filter options again, select "Spotlight Comment": **(fig. 04)**

[image: Image_04]

The "Spotlight Comment" search attribute automatically provides a textfield to type in your search string (yellow).  Click "Save" (green): **(fig. 05)**

[image: Image_05]

Name your new Smart Folder search tool whatever you like, and I would suggest leaving it in the Saved Searches directory (which is located in the Library).

I named my new Smart Folder "Comment Search" (yellow). Leave "Add To Sidebar" (green) checked so that **it will be available for reuse right from the sidebar** without needing to recreate the search over and over!! **(fig. 06)**

[image: Image_07]

Your new search tool is now available from your sidebar.
Command(⌘)+Click (i.e right-click) on the search tool to bring up the contextual menu. Choose "Open in New Tab": **(fig. 07)**

[image: Image_09]

The search tab will look blank.  While still on that tab, go back to the sidebar and Command(⌘)+Click (i.e right-click) on the search tool again to bring up the contextual menu. Choose "Show Search Criteria": **(fig. 08)**

[image: Image_08]

The tab will now show the search tool as it did in **(fig. 05)**.

**Pro Tip #1 :** If you type in a search string, then click "Save", the search string will be saved, so when you open the tool again, you will not need to do "Show Search Criteria" to see the search field in the new tab.  It will already be visible, and you can simply type in your new search string.

**Pro Tip #2 :** After following the instructions for Pro Tip #1, if you then clear out your search string (i.e. backspace it away) and close the tab, the next time you use the search tool from the sidebar, the fields will be visible in the new tab with an empty search string.

This is my first posting to this exchange.  I hope you find it helpful!

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to do it and wanted to document it here for anyone else who may want to know.

1. Navigate to the folder you want to search in, and bring up spotlight
   search (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>)
2. Choose "Raw Query" from the list
   of filter options (add it by choosing "Other..." if you don't see it
   listed)
3. Enter the following in the text field to the right:

   kMDItemFinderComment=*

This will filter the results in the location searched to any file/folder that has a Finder comment.